# Using Variables in CSV

Tags: powershell

I have 3 variables. Each variable is an array of users. 
I'm trying to create a CSV in PowerShell that contains these 3 arrays in separate headers, but the code I'm using isn't working.

Here's the code:

```
$buildcsv = @"
1st Notification, 2nd Notification, 3rd Notification
$1nclient, $2nclient, $3nclient
"@

$excsv = ConvertFrom-Csv $buildcsv
```

However the output only gives me the header, not the related list of users.

```
PS> $excsv

1st Notification 2nd Notification 3rd Notification
---------------- ---------------- ----------------
```

The output that I expect would look like this:

```
1st Notification     2nd Notification       3rd Notification
----------------     ----------------       ----------------
hi.microsoft.com     bye@microsoft.com      pinkpuppy@microsoft.com
hello.microsoft.com  Goodbye@microsoft.com
                     Seeya@microsoft.com
```

Is there a reason why a variable of `System.Array` type wouldn't work?

Comment: give us an example of $1nclient, $2nclient and $3nclient **and** the output you expect.

Comment: Have these variables been populated before you define the multiline string? Also, `$input` is an [automatic variable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx) that shouldn't be used as a regular variable.

Comment: @MartinBrandl 

the examples of all three variables would be a varied list of computers names: $1nclient = hi.microsoft.com, hello.microsoft.com. --- $2nclient = bye@microsoft.com, Goodbye@microsoft.com, Seeya@microsoft.com --- $3nclient = pinkpuppy@microsoft.com

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers 
I've also tried with a different variable there, with the same result. I'll update my question with the other variable.

Comment: ok. and now the output you expect.... Just edit your question...

Comment: @MartinBrandl
done.

Comment: With `$1nclient`, `$2nclient` and `$3nclient` defined before `$buildcsv` I see the values in the output (although not in the format you expect). If you don't you either define the 3 lists after `$buildcsv`, or you have something in your code that you didn't tell us about.

Comment: Oh! You are trying to transpose the arrays. Ok, that's do-able, but not simple. Pretty sure I've posted an answer for this before, let me see if I can find it.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Yeah, transpose the array (I wasn't able to remember the word, thought about reverse.. :-)

Comment: For the desired result it'd probably suffice to create a custom object with 3 properties, join each array with newlines, and assign the wrapped strings to the properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSV Objects are not built in the way you want as discovered in other answers and comments. Normally each row must be its own object that has the same properties as each row before it. We are not making a true CSV here but a collection of lists.

I wanted to show that PowerShell is forgiving with array notation as well as another method to determine how many rows you have.

```
$1nclient = @("hi.microsoft.com", "hello.microsoft.com")
$2nclient = @("bye@microsoft.com", "Goodbye@microsoft.com", "Seeya@microsoft.com")
$3nclient = @("pinkpuppy@microsoft.com")

$maximumEntries = ($1nclient,$2nclient,$3nclient | Measure-Object -Property Count -Maximum).Maximum

0..($maximumEntries - 1) | ForEach-Object{
    [pscustomobject][ordered]@{
        '1st Notification' = $1nclient[$_]
        '2nd Notification' = $2nclient[$_]
        '3rd Notification' = $3nclient[$_]
    }
}
```

Calling a nonexistent array element in PowerShell will return a null. So there is little coding need to account for that. Also don't need to build an array. Just use the pipeline. You can tack on `Export-CSV` on the end of this if you wanted to.

note that it is important we guarantee array types with something like `@()` else PowerShell will treat the string itself as an array and return single letters from positions in a string instead of the first element.

Comment: this code works, but i'm getting added info in the $objects variable. To explain more, I'm populating the $1nclient variables from an imported CSV report. So when i run your code i'm actually getting @{display_client_name=hi@microsoft.com} where display_client_name is the name of the header from the imported csv. –

Comment: You need to expand the property. Just add $1nclient [$_].display_client_name. @justinbeagley

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately this is not how PowerShell works since you have a *list of columns* with there values instead of a *list of rows (records)*. So you have to **transpose** your column array into a collection of rows:

```
$1nclient = @("hi.microsoft.com", "hello.microsoft.com")
$2nclient = @("bye@microsoft.com", "Goodbye@microsoft.com", "Seeya@microsoft.com")
$3nclient = @("pinkpuppy@microsoft.com")

$biggestArray = [Math]::Max($1nclient.Count, ([Math]::Max($2nclient.Count, $3nclient.Count)))

$objects = @()

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $biggestArray; $i++)
{
    if ($1nclient.Count -le $i) { $current1 = '' } else { $current1 = $1nclient[$i]}
    if ($2nclient.Count -le $i) { $current2 = '' } else { $current2 = $2nclient[$i]}
    if ($3nclient.Count -le $i) { $current3 = '' } else { $current3 = $3nclient[$i]}

    $objects += [PsCustomObject]@{
        '1st Notification' = $current1
        '2nd Notification' = $current2
        '3rd Notification' = $current3
    }
} 
$objects
```

---

**Output:**

```
1st Notification    2nd Notification      3rd Notification       
----------------    ----------------      ----------------       
hi.microsoft.com    bye@microsoft.com     pinkpuppy@microsoft.com
hello.microsoft.com Goodbye@microsoft.com                        
                    Seeya@microsoft.com
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But isn't there a more efficient way of populating a column for csv file? What if i created a excel.application object, and a sheet and ran a foreach loop to populate each cell in a column?

Comment: Also - this code works, but i'm getting added info in the $objects variable. To explain more, I'm populating the $1nclient variables from an imported CSV report. So when i run your code i'm actually getting @{display_client_name=hi@microsoft.com}  where display_client_name is the name of the header from the imported csv.